# What does continuous and categorical type options on the x-axis format mean?

Tags: powerbi, visualization, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

On the x-axis format setting I can choose between continuous and categorical.

What does this mean? Can I have an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a date or number for the axis, if you choose continuous, PBI fits the entire scale on the available axis but may not show every point (it may not show all month labels for instance or show every 500 on a scale that goes from 1 to 3000). If you select categorical, every point is shown but may result in scrollbars if you don't have enough room.

Comment: So the decision to choose either is based on whether we want the scroll bar or not (that is otherwise it fits to scale)?